# Pylauncher косяки

Tags: python, windows, pylauncher

python.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

запускаю

```
>python.py
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

>py python.py
3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Почему так? Windows 7.

---

```
>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*

>C:\Windows\py.exe
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36)

>py.exe
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36)
```

Comment: Что происходит если просто `py` запустить? Активировано ли `virtualenv`? В каком порядке `python.exe` в `%PATH%` находятся? Что в `py.ini` написано? Пустая ли `PY_PYTHON` переменная окружения? Выставлен ли `py` для запуска файлов Питона? Что `assoc .py` и `ftype Python.File` показывают?

Comment: @jfs Ассоциации с C:\Windows\py.exe, если его запустить, что с путем что без - открывается 2.х как и положено. virtualenv и переменных нет. Где этот py.ini?

Comment: Где это еще спросить можно?

Comment: Если вы `py.ini` не создавали, то можно не искать. Можно попробовать добавить: `import os; print(os.environ['PATH']) \n import shutil \n if hasattr(shutil, 'which'): print(shutil.which('python'))` и заново оба варианта запустить (может вы первый вариант без shebang ещё запускали).

Comment: @jfs python2 в path вообще нет. А почему python запускает python.**py**? Это какое-то нововведение семерки?

Comment: Чтобы убедиться, что `py` используется для запуска скрипта, можно попробовать разные shebang и последить за версиями. Для тестирования запусить: `set PATH=C:\Путь к Питон 3\директории;%PATH% & тест.py & C:\Widnows\py.exe тест.py` затем убрать `env` и использовать `#!python`, затем `#!python3`, затем  `#!python2`. Обновите вопрос с результатами.

Comment: @jfs не, а что еще может использоваться (assoc/fsutil выше)? И я кстати не исследование провожу а пытаюсь заставить работать на 7 говно, которое до этого работало на xp.

Comment: ассоциации у Вас и так правильные (`py` и должен запускать `.py` файлы). Команды необходимы, чтобы диагностировать Вашу проблему

Comment: Т.е. что так что так файл запускается py.exe? Так почему он в одном случае запускает 3 а в другом 2?

Comment: Вопрос, почему `> file.py` отличается от `> py file.py`, команды из моего комментария должны помочь диагностировать.

Comment: @jfs **Как?** И в том и в другом случае должен запускаться py.exe

Comment: Если нет результатов, не оставляйте мне больше комментарии

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы пытаетесь выяснить, а проверять все подряд до бесконечности не хочу.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, [`py` запускает самую последнюю версию Питона **2**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). Наличие
 `#! /usr/bin/env python` заставляет `py` использовать первый `python.exe`, который можно в `os.environ['PATH']` найти (`shutil.which('python')`), который может относится к версии Питона 3.

Comment: Где это описано? https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher  "#!python    -> the default Python (usually the most recent Python 2.x)". И почему запуск через file.py и py file.py дает разные результаты?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: `#! /usr/bin/env python` и `#! python` разные вещи. *"Почему запуск через file.py и py file.py дает разные результаты?"* -- (а) Вы разные редакции file.py запускали (б) у Вас несколько py.exe разных версий установлено (одна с поддержкой env, другая без) (в) других вариантов нет, если virtualenv не используется и переменные окружения одинаковые и `py` правильно с ассоциирован и настройки по умолчанию. Чтобы отличить `(а)` от `(б)`, запустите [код из моего комментария](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456707/pylauncher-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment493938_456707)

Comment: Это юмор? Разумеется, file.py одинаковые. Выхлоп assoc выше. Код я запускал. `#! /usr/bin/env python` и `#! python` на xp работали одинаково.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: это не юмор. Я встречал случаи когда программист  запускал не ту версию приложения, отличную от той, которую только что редактировал. Или вносил "тривиальные" изменения без тестирования, о которых забыл и которые позже вызывали баги. Я не вижу результата `print(shutil.which('python'))` в вопросе.

Comment: Я его тоже не вижу, наверно, его нету на винде (which).

Comment: @SmitJohnth: [`shutil.which()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) есть везде.

Comment: jfs вы свой код-то читали, конкретно это `if hasattr(shutil, 'which'): print(shutil.which('python'))`? И у меня его нет.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: `shutil.which()` -- есть везде (и на Винде, и Маке, и на Linux), а `hasattr()` необходим потому что в Питоне 2 его нет (но одна из команд, у Вас запускает Питон 3.4, на котором  `shutil.which()` точно есть). Ясно?

Comment: Вы не говорили что код надо запускать на питоне 3. И мы куда-то далековато уходим от вопроса, вам не кажется?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: я не говорил, потому что ожидаю, что Вы повторите  две команды, которые были у Вас в вопросе с самого начала. Код должен работать в обоих присутствующих вариантах (`hasattr()` для Питон 2 варианта и результат `shutil.which()` для Питон 3 -- посмотрите на вопрос, обратите внимание на Python 3.4 в результатах).